# How to display video in collectionviewcell and view video in a different view controller in swift 5

Tags: swift, video, uicollectionview

I am new to swift development. I am able to select a video in the photo library but I need help displaying it in a collection view cell.
I am not sure what the correct syntax is. 
Secondly, I would like to be able to select the video and view and play the video in a different view controller.

```
var vid = [NSURL]() // I don't think this is right


extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {


     if (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String) != nil {

         vid.append(video) //this is wrong but I don't know how to display video in a cell
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add `UICollectionView` inside your view controller of storyboard. Connect `dataSource` and `delegate`.

Then create new class file of `UICollectionViewCell` and add following code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: UIView!

    var avQueuePlayer   : AVQueuePlayer?
    var avPlayerLayer   : AVPlayerLayer?

    func addPlayer(for url: URL) {
        self.avQueuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(url: url)
        self.avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avQueuePlayer!)
        self.avPlayerLayer?.frame = self.playerView.bounds
        self.avPlayerLayer?.fillMode = .both
        self.playerView.layer.addSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer!)
        self.avQueuePlayer?.play()
    }
}
```

Also, set this `VideoCell` to collection view cell and set same name identifier of collection view cell. Apart from that add `UIView` in collection view cell from storyboard and connect outlet to `playerView`.

In your `ViewController` class where collectionView placed add following code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cvVideoPlayer : UICollectionView!

    var arrVideoList    =   [URL]()

    lazy var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        return imagePicker
    }()

    func openMediaLibrary() {
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        // 1. After picking video url append two array
        if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
            if !self.arrVideoList.contains(url) {
                self.arrVideoList.append(url)
                self.cvVideoPlayer.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrVideoList.count
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell

        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.addPlayer(for: self.arrVideoList[indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let videoUrl = self.arrVideoList[indexPath.item]

        // Code to present another view controller and pass above url
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

The above code will play video in collection view cell. To play video when click on cell in another view controller, use same code to play vide which are used for cell in that controller and just pass it from `didSelectItemAt` method.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! I will give this a try. I currently have code to choose an image but would also like to choose image and video.Would I be able to use the code above to display for image and video?

Comment: Yes, you can use above code to display image. You should check extension of picked url and based on that display image or video.

Comment: I am getting "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'" at "if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {" at didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function. Could I IM you?

Comment: Also getting "Fatal error: Index out of range" at cell.addPlayer(for: self.arrVideoList[indexPath.item])

Comment: Which XCode version are you using ?

Comment: @user10503759, Please check my updated answer how to open ImagePicker for video.

Comment: Hello, I am using Xcode 11. I am getting the same error above when I try to add image and video. I am unable to paste the code in here because of the characters size. Can I email it to you?

Comment: Yes. Do it on chauhan.sagar4893@gmail.com

Comment: I will check it tomorrow and let you know what an issue with your code.

Comment: I sent you an email